# Should rake spec in Rspec 3 always end with "rake aborted"

Tags: rspec2

Everytime I run rake spec with Rspec2 and Rails3 it finishes with rake aborted. Wondering if this is normal behaviour or if I have made some mistake along the way?

```
........
Finished in 0.01589 seconds
7 examples, 6 failures, 1 pending


rake aborted!
ruby -S bundle exec rspec "./spec/helpers/homes_helper_spec.rb" "./spec/models/habit_spec.rb" failed
/Users/jack/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p174/gems/rspec-core-2.0.1/lib/rspec/core/rake_task.rb:117:in `initialize'
/Users/jack/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p174/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1112:in `verbose'
/Users/jack/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p174/gems/rspec-core-2.0.1/lib/rspec/core/rake_task.rb:109:in `send'
/Users/jack/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p174/gems/rspec-core-2.0.1/lib/rspec/core/rake_task.rb:109:in `initialize'
/Users/jack/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p174/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in `call'
/Users/jack/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p174/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in `execute'
/Users/jack/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p174/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in `each'
/Users/jack/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p174/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in `execute'
/Users/jack/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p174/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:597:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/jack/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p174/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
/Users/jack/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p174/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:590:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/jack/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p174/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:583:in `invoke'
/Users/jack/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p174/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2051:in `invoke_task'
/Users/jack/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p174/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `top_level'
/Users/jack/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p174/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `each'
/Users/jack/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p174/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `top_level'
/Users/jack/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p174/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/jack/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p174/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2023:in `top_level'
/Users/jack/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p174/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2001:in `run'
/Users/jack/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p174/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/jack/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p174/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1998:in `run'
/Users/jack/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p174/gems/rake-0.8.7/bin/rake:31
/Users/jack/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p174/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/Users/jack/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p174/bin/rake:19
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its normal when you've got failures.

Answer (score 2):

At the moment, doing `rspec spec/` will not produce the huge "rake aborted!" stack trace, but by default, your Rakefile task will.  To suppress this, try sticking something like this in your Rakefile.

```
# This clears the default spec task from MyApp::Application.load_tasks
Rake::Task["spec"].clear 

# This defines your new spec task with a suppressed stack trace
RSpec::Core::RakeTask.new(:spec) do |t|
  t.fail_on_error = false
end
```